# How do I receive emails when I receive a response?

Tags: support, email, responses, alerts

I have my preferences set to 3 hours, but I do not receive email alerts when I receive an inbox message.  Is there a setting that I need to set?

Comment: You didn't read your inbox-message? You only get an e-mail if you don't touch that red thinghy for 3 hours.

Comment: I didn't.  I received these emails in my inbox, but I don't receive the ones in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As noted by rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269510/how-do-i-receive-emails-when-i-receive-a-response#comment873310_269510), only unread notifications are emailed:

> [image]

(which seems to be pretty intuitive by the way)

Workarounds:

1. If you have an iPhone or an Android phone, you can download the SE app which would alert you notifications.
2. There's a user responses feed. `{site}/feeds/user/{id}/responses`. You can try [setting it up](http://chronicle.com/blogs/profhacker/send-an-rss-feed-to-your-email-account/50319) to work with email (have't you known that your inbox notifications ain't private actually ;D).

   Example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/309567/responses

Comment: I have that parameter checked.  Thank you for the other options.  I did receive these notifications.  It seems to be the ones in StackOverflow that don't come through.

Comment: Does that responses feed also include mod messages?